# flutter fire base upload get stuck due to null check

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

when running the app these methods should work fine when saving the menu but not when saving to a subcollection

i changed for some other methods but all didn't work i tried using the app check because it was showing no app check token found i set up the dependencies now it says Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: `com.google.firebase.FirebaseException`: No AppCheckProvider installed.`

```
validateUploadForm() async {
    if (imageXFile != null) {
      if (shortInfoController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          titleController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          descriptionController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          priceController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        // if its true set uploading to true and start process indicator
        setState(() {
          uploading = true;
        });

        //upload image
        String downloadUrl = await uploadImage(File(imageXFile!.path));

        //save info to firestore

        saveInfo(downloadUrl);
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) {
            return ErrorDialog(
              message: "Please write title and info for menu.",
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) {
          return ErrorDialog(
            message: "Please pick an image for menu.",
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
saveInfo(String downloadUrl) {
    final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("sellers")
        .doc(sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"))
        .collection("menus")
        .doc(widget.model!.menuID)
        .collection("items")
        .doc(uniqueIdName);

    // Information to pass to Firebase
    ref.set({
      "itemID": uniqueIdName,
      "menuID": widget.model!.menuID,
      "sellerUID": sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"),
      "sellerName": sharedPreferences!.getString("name"),
      "shortInfo": shortInfoController.text.toString(),
      "longDescription": descriptionController.text.toString(),
      "price": int.parse(priceController.text),
      "title": titleController.text.toString(),
      "publishedDate": DateTime.now(),
      "status": "available",
      "thumbnailUrl": downloadUrl,
    }).then((value) {
      final itemsref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items");
      itemsref.doc(uniqueIdName).set({
        "itemID": uniqueIdName,
        "menuID": widget.model!.menuID,
        "sellerUID": sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"),
        "sellerName": sharedPreferences!.getString("name"),
        "shortInfo": shortInfoController.text.toString(),
        "longDescription": descriptionController.text.toString(),
        "price": int.parse(priceController.text),
        "title": titleController.text.toString(),
        "publishedDate": DateTime.now(),
        "status": "available",
        "thumbnailUrl": downloadUrl,
      });


}).then(
          (value) {
        clearMenuUploadFrom();

        setState(
              () {
            uniqueIdName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
            uploading = false;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.